# How to assign the sum of a dictionaries values to a variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, raw-input

This dictionary is created by a user:

```
p2u = raw_input("Player 2 enter the amount of units you have: ")
if p2u == 1:
    p2d={'Unit 1': 50}
    p2units = 50
if p2u == 2:
    p2d={'Unit 1': 50, 'Unit 2': 50}
    p2units = 100
if p2u == 3:
    p2d={'Unit 1': 50, 'Unit 2': 50, 'Unit 3': 50}
    p2units = 150
```

Now lets say the user inputs 3, how to a make the sum of the variables equal to a variable called 'Amount'?

Comment: which variables are you trying to sum?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
amount = 0

for key, value in p2d.items():
    amount += value
```

Or

```
amount = sum(p2d.values())
```

You need the following:

```
p2u = int(raw_input("Player 2 enter the amount of units you have: "))
```

as your if statements are checking for ints while your `raw_input` gives a string('1' etc.)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you find this solved your issue, please consider accepting it as the answer(the tick under the votes).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`sum()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
p2d = {'Unit 1': 50, 'Unit 2': 50, 'Unit 3': 50}
amount = sum(p2d.values())
```

Also, note that p2u is an string (if you want to test the type of a variable `print type(p2u)`), and in the `if` statements you are comparing it with an `int`. You could solve this by 2 ways.

First way, cast `p2u` to an integer:

```
p2u = int(raw_input(...))
```

Second way, compare p2u (as string) with strings:

```
p2u = raw_input(...)
if p2u == "1":
    ...
```

Comment: sum(d1.values()) doesn't work

Comment: @user2757442 why? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what value the question is after. The following code will add up all of the values from any of the p2d dictionaries:

```
Amount = sum(p2d.values())
```

Listing the values is done with :

```
>>> p2d={'Unit 1': 50, 'Unit 2': 50, 'Unit 3': 50}
>>> p2d.values()
[50,50,50]
```

Adding the numbers in a list:

```
sum([50,50,50])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The output of raw_input is a string, not an integer. Translate it to integer:

   `p2u = int(p2u)`
2. Use sum:

   `p2units = sum(p2d.values())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extended version:

```
import sys

# Python 2/3 compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange
else:
    inp = input
    rng = range

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name, men=50):
        self.name = name
        self.men  = men

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:5s}: {} men".format(self.name, self.men)

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, units=None):
        self.name = name
        if units is None:
            units = get_int("How many units does {} have? ".format(self.name))
        self.units = [Unit("Unit {}".format(i)) for i in rng(1, units+1)]

    @property
    def men(self):
        return sum(u.men for u in self.units)

    def __str__(self):
        units = ''.join("\n  {}".format(u) for u in self.units)
        return "{}{}\nTotal: {} men".format(self.name, units, self.men)

def main():
    num_players = get_int("How many players? ")
    players = [Player("Player {}".format(i)) for i in rng(1, num_players+1)]

    print('')
    print("\n\n".join(str(p) for p in players))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
How many players? 3
How many units does Player 1 have? 2
How many units does Player 2 have? 1
How many units does Player 3 have? 9

Player 1
  Unit 1: 50 men
  Unit 2: 50 men
Total: 100 men

Player 2
  Unit 1: 50 men
Total: 50 men

Player 3
  Unit 1: 50 men
  Unit 2: 50 men
  Unit 3: 50 men
  Unit 4: 50 men
  Unit 5: 50 men
  Unit 6: 50 men
  Unit 7: 50 men
  Unit 8: 50 men
  Unit 9: 50 men
Total: 450 men
```